# DNN Profile update on login - existing values not displayed

Tags: dotnetnuke-5

We have recently changed our website configuration to make certain fields mandatory. We also set "Require valid profile for login" to True, so that existing users can fill out the missing information the next time they log in.
The problem is that when users log in, the profile update form displayed to them is totally blank. DNN does not pre-fill the form with information that the user already provided in the past. Even fields such as First Name and Last Name are empty.
Is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured out the problem.
We had put some custom code in Page_Load event to inspect the initial profile values. Once we removed it, everything works fine.